# how to give a max-height to the PrimeNg ListBox using listStyleClass attribue

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, inline-styles

The PrimeNG ListBox component mentions the attribute `listStyleClass`

I have managed to set the max-width using an inline style using the `listStyle` attribute

```
    <p-listbox id="myListbox" class="my-list" [options]="listItems()"
      [listStyle]="{ 'max-height': '300px' }">
```

but I would prefer not to have inline styles and use the `listStyleClass`  to get the same result

```
    <p-listbox id="myListbox" class="my-list" [options]="listItems()"
      listStyleClass="customListStyleClass">
```

when I put in my component css

```
.customListStyleClass {
   max-height : 300px;
}
```

nothing happens. How do I achieve the same result without inline styles

This is the docs https://primeng.org/listbox and demo can be created by opening the examples in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me when I did like

```html
    <p-listbox id="myListbox" class="my-list" [options]="listItems()"
      listStyleClass="customListStyleClass">
```

and in scss file

```css
:host ::ng-deep .customListStyleClass {
   max-height : 300px;
}
```